# How to fix "os.asm:113: error: TIMES value -138 is negative" in assembly language

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, osdev

I'm developing an operating system in assembly language. 
At a certain time i get this error from NASM:

> os.asm:113: error: TIMES value -138 is negative

I want to take this project to the end. Only the errors like that despair me!

Here is the code:

```
BITS 16

start:
    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set up 4K stack space after this bootloader
    add ax, 288     ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes per paragraph
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096
    mov ax, 07C0h       ; Set data segment to where we're loaded
    mov ds, ax
    call cls
    MOV AH, 06h    ; Scroll up function
    XOR AL, AL     ; Clear entire screen
    XOR CX, CX     ; Upper left corner CH=row, CL=column
    MOV DX, 184FH  ; lower right corner DH=row, DL=column 
    MOV BH, 1Eh    ; YellowOnBlue
    INT 10H
    mov si, text_string ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine
push bx ;push registers
push cx
push dx
mov ah,0h
int 16h
       cmp al, '1'
       je reboot
       cmp al, '2'
       je shutdown
       cmp al, '3'
       je about
       cmp al, '4'
       je message
       cmp al, '5'
       je shutdown
       cmp al, '6'
       je credits

       jmp $            ; Jump here - infinite loop!


    text_string db '|Main Menu| |Smile OS V1.4|',13,10,'1) Reboot',13,10,'2) Shutdown',13,10,'3) About',13,10,'4) Message',13,10,'5) System Halt',13,10,'6) Credits',0
    about_string db '|About|',13,10,'Smile OS is a console based operating system in assembly language. 8 hours of intense work done by Alex~s Software. Many errors but solved and very successful.',13,10,'Press any key to go back!',0
    message_str db '|Message|',10,13,'Hello, World!',13,10,'Press any key to go back!',0
    cr_str db '|Credits|',13,10,'Copyright © 2018 Alex~s Software',13,10,'Main Programer: Alex',13,10,'Graphichs: What graphics?',13,10,'Idea:  nobody :)',0

reboot:
mov ax, 0
int 19h

shutdown:
mov ax, 0x1000
mov ax, ss
mov sp, 0xf000
mov ax, 0x5307
mov bx, 0x0001
mov cx, 0x0003
int 0x15

credits:
call cls
mov si, cr_str  ; Put string position into SI
call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine
push bx ;push registers
push cx
push dx
mov ah,0h
int 16h
je start

message:
call cls
mov si, message_str ; Put string position into SI
call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine
push bx ;push registers
push cx
push dx
mov ah,0h
int 16h
je start

cls:
  pusha
  mov ah, 0x00
  mov al, 0x03  ; text mode 80x25 16 colours
  int 0x10
  popa
  ret

about:
call cls
mov si, about_string    ; Put string position into SI
call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine
push bx ;push registers
push cx
push dx
mov ah,0h
int 16h 
je start

print_string:           ; Routine: output string in SI to screen
    mov ah, 0Eh     ; int 10h 'print char' function

.repeat:
    lodsb           ; Get character from string
    cmp al, 0
    je .done        ; If char is zero, end of string
    int 10h         ; Otherwise, print it
    jmp .repeat

.done:
    ret     

times   512 - ($ - $$)    db  0
signature       dw      0xaa55
```

Why Times value is negative? Hhy others do not get the same error? (Or like that)

I use this :

> NASM version 2.14
>
> Oracle VM VirtualBox version 6.0.0_RC1
>
> rawwrite dd for windows version 0.5.

For compile:

```
nasm os.asm -f bin -o os.bin  
dd if=/dev/zero of=os.img bs=1024 count=1440   
dd if=os.bin of=os.img
```

Comment: related: [Assembly Why when i modify the code the result gets unbootable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53796349) (from the same user), the answer there has lots of details on bootloaders.  It's mostly about the `512 - ($-$$)` instead of `510` bug, but also mentions the size limit.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I have read it more carefully now, and yes I see that it's mostly about being too big (I wish I could edit my first comment).  But it doesn't start off with a quick / simple explanation of exactly where *this* error message comes from, so a separate Q&A with simple answers is appropriate.  Not everything related question should be an actual duplicate of a big tutorial, sometimes other forms of linking are more appropriate.  This came up recently on meta in [Please help me improve my canonical post about dynamic evaluation in pandas](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377890)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** : Your code and data is too big and collided with the boot signature in the last 2 bytes of the file. The code below is a floppy disk bootloader that reads a second stage (your kernel) and transfers control to it. The provided BPB is for a 1.44MiB floppy. Unlike a bootloader, stage2 will be loaded to physical address 0x07e00 (right after the bootloader in memory). This allows your code to be up to 32.5KiB in size. Your second stage can read more sectors if needed. This code has been designed so others can use this as a template for reading a second stage and transferring control to it.

---

This question has actually been already answered under your previous [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53796604/3857942). There is a warning about the padding using `times 512 - ($ - $$) db 0x00` needing to be 510 and not 512. The answer warns of too much code and data (exceeding 512 bytes), and a way to get better error/warnings from NASM about the size. The note in my other answer summarizes the size issue as:

> If the file os.bin is **more than 512 bytes** then you will need to use the BIOS to read more disk sectors into memory manually. The disk reads from a floppy can be done with [INT 13h/AH=2h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm).

What wasn't provided was a mechanism (example) that uses NASM and INT 13h/AH=2h to read more disk sectors (aka stage2) into memory right after the bootloader at physical address 0x07E00. The code is commented, but it effectively does:

- The start up code properly sets up segment registers and uses the boot drive passed by the BIOS in the *DL* register. This is discussed in my [Stackoverflow General Bootloader Tips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942)
- The stack is placed below the bootloader at 0x0000:0x7c00. Setting your own stack is important when reading data into memory outside 0x7c00 to 0x7dff since you don't know where the BIOS set the default stack (*SS:SP*).
- Presents itself as a 1.44MB floppy with a BIOS Parameter Block to make it [compatible with USB Floppy Drive Emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320115/3857942) booting on real hardware.
- Stage2 is read a sector at a time using INT 13h/AH=2h starting at 0x07e00. It supports retry on errors.
- Once Stage2 is finished loading the kernel, the bootloader transfers control to the stage2 code at 0x0000:0x7E00 (`stage2_start`)
- Stage2 can contain the code you wish to run. You will have 32.5KiB of space to test your code rather than the limitations of a single boot sector (512 bytes).
- Stage2's disk sectors immediately follow the boot sector in the disk image.
- Your Stage2 (kernel) code goes into `stage2.asm`. `stage2.asm` gets assembled into `stage2.bin` and `os.asm` includes the binary file `stage2.bin` so that the size of stage2 can be determined for purposes of loading it into memory by the bootloader.
- `stage2.asm` must use `ORG 0x7e00` since the process above will be loading this code to 0x7e00, so the ORG (origin point) must be set to match.
- This bootloader will pass the original boot drive number (passed by the BIOS) in register DL to the code running in stage2.
- The file `stage2info.inc` defines constants to determine what the origin point of stage2 is, and what segment and offset should be used for the FAR JMP when transferring control to it. The default version of this file assumes stage2 is accessed via 0x0000:0x7e00. An alternative version<sup>2</sup> of the file can be used to make that 0x07e0:0x0000. The latter version allows your code to take up a full 64kb segment.

---

### The Code:

**bpb.inc**:

```
    jmp boot_start
    TIMES 3-($-$$) DB 0x90   ; Support 2 or 3 byte encoded JMPs before BPB.

bpb_disk_info:
    ; Dos 4.0 EBPB 1.44MB floppy
    OEMname:           db    "mkfs.fat"  ; mkfs.fat is what OEMname mkdosfs uses
    bytesPerSector:    dw    512
    sectPerCluster:    db    1
    reservedSectors:   dw    1
    numFAT:            db    2
    numRootDirEntries: dw    224
    numSectors:        dw    2880
    mediaType:         db    0xf0
    numFATsectors:     dw    9
    sectorsPerTrack:   dw    18
    numHeads:          dw    2
    numHiddenSectors:  dd    0
    numSectorsHuge:    dd    0
    driveNum:          db    0
    reserved:          db    0
    signature:         db    0x29
    volumeID:          dd    0x2d7e5a1a
    volumeLabel:       db    "NO NAME    "
    fileSysType:       db    "FAT12   "
```

**stage2info.inc**:

```
STAGE2_ABS_ADDR   equ 0x07e00    ; Physical address of stage2

; Segment and Offset to use to transfer (FAR JMP) control to Stage2
;     Segment:Offset = 0x0000:0x7e00
STAGE2_RUN_SEG   equ 0x0000
STAGE2_RUN_OFS   equ STAGE2_ABS_ADDR
```

**os.asm**:

```
%include "stage2info.inc"

STAGE2_LOAD_SEG  equ STAGE2_ABS_ADDR>>4
                                ; Segment to start reading Stage2 into
                                ;     right after bootloader

STAGE2_LBA_START equ 1          ; Logical Block Address(LBA) Stage2 starts on
                                ;     LBA 1 = sector after boot sector
STAGE2_LBA_END   equ STAGE2_LBA_START + NUM_STAGE2_SECTORS
                                ; Logical Block Address(LBA) Stage2 ends at
DISK_RETRIES     equ 3          ; Number of times to retry on disk error

bits 16
ORG 0x7c00

; Include a BPB (1.44MB floppy with FAT12) to be more comaptible with USB floppy media
%include "bpb.inc"

boot_start:
    xor ax, ax                  ; DS=SS=ES=0 for stage2 loading
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax                  ; Stack at 0x0000:0x7c00
    mov sp, 0x7c00
    cld                         ; Set string instructions to use forward movement

    ; Read Stage2 1 sector at a time until stage2 is completely loaded
load_stage2:
    mov [bootDevice], dl        ; Save boot drive
    mov di, STAGE2_LOAD_SEG     ; DI = Current segment to read into
    mov si, STAGE2_LBA_START    ; SI = LBA that stage2 starts at
    jmp .chk_for_last_lba       ; Check to see if we are last sector in stage2

.read_sector_loop:
    mov bp, DISK_RETRIES        ; Set disk retry count

    call lba_to_chs             ; Convert current LBA to CHS
    mov es, di                  ; Set ES to current segment number to read into
    xor bx, bx                  ; Offset zero in segment

.retry:
    mov ax, 0x0201              ; Call function 0x02 of int 13h (read sectors)
                                ;     AL = 1 = Sectors to read
    int 0x13                    ; BIOS Disk interrupt call
    jc .disk_error              ; If CF set then disk error

.success:
    add di, 512>>4              ; Advance to next 512 byte segment (0x20*16=512)
    inc si                      ; Next LBA

.chk_for_last_lba:
    cmp si, STAGE2_LBA_END      ; Have we reached the last stage2 sector?
    jl .read_sector_loop        ;     If we haven't then read next sector

.stage2_loaded:
    mov ax, STAGE2_RUN_SEG      ; Set up the segments appropriate for Stage2 to run
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    ; FAR JMP to the Stage2 entry point at physical address 0x07e00
    jmp STAGE2_RUN_SEG:STAGE2_RUN_OFS

.disk_error:
    xor ah, ah                  ; Int13h/AH=0 is drive reset
    int 0x13
    dec bp                      ; Decrease retry count
    jge .retry                  ; If retry count not exceeded then try again

error_end:
    ; Unrecoverable error; print drive error; enter infinite loop
    mov si, diskErrorMsg        ; Display disk error message
    call print_string
    cli
.error_loop:
    hlt
    jmp .error_loop

; Function: print_string
;           Display a string to the console on display page 0
;
; Inputs:   SI = Offset of address to print
; Clobbers: AX, BX, SI

print_string:
    mov ah, 0x0e                ; BIOS tty Print
    xor bx, bx                  ; Set display page to 0 (BL)
    jmp .getch
.repeat:
    int 0x10                    ; print character
.getch:
    lodsb                       ; Get character from string
    test al,al                  ; Have we reached end of string?
    jnz .repeat                 ;     if not process next character
.end:
    ret

;    Function: lba_to_chs
; Description: Translate Logical block address to CHS (Cylinder, Head, Sector).
;              Works for all valid FAT12 compatible disk geometries.
;
;   Resources: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0607.htm
;              https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing#CHS_conversion
;              https://stackoverflow.com/q/45434899/3857942
;              Sector    = (LBA mod SPT) + 1
;              Head      = (LBA / SPT) mod HEADS
;              Cylinder  = (LBA / SPT) / HEADS
;
;      Inputs: SI = LBA
;     Outputs: DL = Boot Drive Number
;              DH = Head
;              CH = Cylinder (lower 8 bits of 10-bit cylinder)
;              CL = Sector/Cylinder
;                   Upper 2 bits of 10-bit Cylinders in upper 2 bits of CL
;                   Sector in lower 6 bits of CL
;
;       Notes: Output registers match expectation of Int 13h/AH=2 inputs
;
lba_to_chs:
    push ax                     ; Preserve AX
    mov ax, si                  ; Copy LBA to AX
    xor dx, dx                  ; Upper 16-bit of 32-bit value set to 0 for DIV
    div word [sectorsPerTrack]  ; 32-bit by 16-bit DIV : LBA / SPT
    mov cl, dl                  ; CL = S = LBA mod SPT
    inc cl                      ; CL = S = (LBA mod SPT) + 1
    xor dx, dx                  ; Upper 16-bit of 32-bit value set to 0 for DIV
    div word [numHeads]         ; 32-bit by 16-bit DIV : (LBA / SPT) / HEADS
    mov dh, dl                  ; DH = H = (LBA / SPT) mod HEADS
    mov dl, [bootDevice]        ; boot device, not necessary to set but convenient
    mov ch, al                  ; CH = C(lower 8 bits) = (LBA / SPT) / HEADS
    shl ah, 6                   ; Store upper 2 bits of 10-bit Cylinder into
    or  cl, ah                  ;     upper 2 bits of Sector (CL)
    pop ax                      ; Restore scratch registers
    ret

; Uncomment these lines if not using a BPB (via bpb.inc)
; numHeads:        dw 2         ; 1.44MB Floppy has 2 heads & 18 sector per track
; sectorsPerTrack: dw 18

bootDevice:      db 0x00
diskErrorMsg:    db "Unrecoverable disk error!", 0

; Pad boot sector to 510 bytes and add 2 byte boot signature for 512 total bytes
TIMES 510-($-$$) db  0
dw 0xaa55

; Beginning of stage2. This is at 0x7E00 and will allow your stage2 to be 32.5KiB
; before running into problems. DL will be set to the drive number originally
; passed to us by the BIOS.

NUM_STAGE2_SECTORS equ (stage2_end-stage2_start+511) / 512
                                ; Number of 512 byte sectors stage2 uses.

stage2_start:
    ; Insert stage2 binary here. It is done this way since we
    ; can determine the size(and number of sectors) to load since
    ;     Size = stage2_end-stage2_start
    incbin "stage2.bin"

; End of stage2. Make sure this label is LAST in this file!
stage2_end:
```

You place all the code you want to test in the file `stage2.asm` which will be included by my version of `os.asm`. A version of your code with the unnecessary parts at the beginning and end removed is:

**stage2.asm**

```
%include "stage2info.inc"
ORG STAGE2_RUN_OFS

BITS 16

start:
    ; Removed the segment and stack code
    call cls
    MOV AH, 06h    ; Scroll up function
    XOR AL, AL     ; Clear entire screen
    XOR CX, CX     ; Upper left corner CH=row, CL=column
    MOV DX, 184FH  ; lower right corner DH=row, DL=column
    MOV BH, 1Eh    ; YellowOnBlue
    INT 10H
    mov si, text_string ; Put string position into SI
    call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine
push bx ;push registers
push cx
push dx
mov ah,0h
int 16h
       cmp al, '1'
       je reboot
       cmp al, '2'
       je shutdown
       cmp al, '3'
       je about
       cmp al, '4'
       je message
       cmp al, '5'
       je shutdown
       cmp al, '6'
       je credits

       jmp $            ; Jump here - infinite loop!


    text_string db '|Main Menu| |Smile OS V1.4|',13,10,'1) Reboot',13,10,'2) Shutdown',13,10,'3) About',13,10,'4) Message',13,10,'5) System Halt',13,10,'6) Credits',0
    about_string db '|About|',13,10,'Smile OS is a console based operating system in assembly language. 8 hours of intense work done by Alex~s Software. Many errors but solved and very successful.',13,10,'Press any key to go back!',0
    message_str db '|Message|',10,13,'Hello, World!',13,10,'Press any key to go back!',0
    cr_str db '|Credits|',13,10,'Copyright © 2018 Alex~s Software',13,10,'Main Programer: Alex',13,10,'Graphichs: What graphics?',13,10,'Idea:  nobody :)',0

reboot:
mov ax, 0
int 19h

shutdown:
mov ax, 0x1000
mov ax, ss
mov sp, 0xf000
mov ax, 0x5307
mov bx, 0x0001
mov cx, 0x0003
int 0x15

credits:
call cls
mov si, cr_str  ; Put string position into SI
call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine
push bx ;push registers
push cx
push dx
mov ah,0h
int 16h
je start

message:
call cls
mov si, message_str ; Put string position into SI
call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine
push bx ;push registers
push cx
push dx
mov ah,0h
int 16h
je start

cls:
  pusha
  mov ah, 0x00
  mov al, 0x03  ; text mode 80x25 16 colours
  int 0x10
  popa
  ret

about:
call cls
mov si, about_string    ; Put string position into SI
call print_string   ; Call our string-printing routine
push bx ;push registers
push cx
push dx
mov ah,0h
int 16h
je start

print_string:           ; Routine: output string in SI to screen
    mov ah, 0Eh     ; int 10h 'print char' function

.repeat:
    lodsb           ; Get character from string
    cmp al, 0
    je .done        ; If char is zero, end of string
    int 10h         ; Otherwise, print it
    jmp .repeat

.done:
    ret
```

You then assemble and build the disk image with these commands<sup>1</sup>:

```
# Build stage2 (kernel) FIRST as os.asm will include stage2.bin
nasm -f bin stage2.asm -o stage2.bin
# Build and combine stage1 (boot sector) and stage2 (kernel)
nasm -f bin os.asm -o os.bin

# Build 1.44MB disk image
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1024 count=1440
dd if=os.bin of=disk.img conv=notrunc
```

Lines starting with `#` are just comments and are not commands.

---

### Screenshots

The main menu appears as:

[image]

The credit screen appears as:

[image]

---

### Notes:

<sup>1</sup>You use these commands which contains an error:

```
nasm os.asm -f bin -o os.bin  
dd if=/dev/zero of=os.img bs=1024 count=1440   
dd if=os.bin of=os.img
```

The last line should be `dd if=os.bin of=os.img conv=notrunc` so that the 1.44MB disk image doesn't get truncated when the `os.bin` file is written to it. If you look at the size of your disk image you will probably see that is **not the expected 1474560**.

---

<sup>2</sup>An alternative `stage2info.inc` file to use 0x07e0:0x0000 instead of 0x0000:0x7e00 to transfer control to stage2:

```
STAGE2_ABS_ADDR   equ 0x07e00    ; Physical address of stage2

; Segment and Offset to use to transfer (FAR JMP) control to Stage2
;     Segment:Offset = 0x07e0:0x0000
STAGE2_RUN_SEG   equ STAGE2_ABS_ADDR>>4
STAGE2_RUN_OFS   equ 0x0000
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your line:

```
times 512 - ($ - $$) db 0
```

is meant to fill up the rest of the 512-byte chunk of memory with zeroes, it's likely that you have *already* exceeded that (by roughly 138 bytes). You'll probably need to just shorten your code (or make some of those strings a little less verbose) so it fits.

My advice would be to start with `about_string`, which seems ***way*** more than necessary. Removing the (rather self-serving)`" 8 hours of intense work done by Alex~s Software. Many errors but solved and very successful."` would be a good start as it would save 93 bytes. In addition, at the cost of a few extra bytes of code, you could remove the duplicate `"Press any key to go back!"` (with leading and trailing <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>LF</kbd>).

This could be done with something like:

```
about_string db '|About|',13,10,'Smile OS is a console based operating system in assembly language.'
any_key      db 13,10,'Press any key to go back!',0
message_str db '|Message|',10,13,'Hello, World!',0
```

The about string could then be printed in exactly the same manner (because `about_string` has no terminating `0` hence will also print `any_key`) but the message string would change into a two-step operation:

```
mov si, message_str     --> mov si, message_str
call print_string           call print_string
                            mov si, any_key
                            call print_string
```

That will save about another 20 bytes, giving you a saving of about 113 of the 138 bytes.

Other than that, there appear to be a few minor things that could save very small amounts of space such as converting:

```
mov ah, 0x00
mov al, 0x03
```

into:

```
mov ax, 0x0003
```

or refactoring the key input into a function (this will also keep your stack balanced, something your current code does not appear to do, although I'm not actually sure that it's necessary - the documentation seems to suggest that `ax` is the only register affected, meaning you could probably remove the pushes and pops):

```
get_kbd: push bx
         push cx
         push dx
         xor  ax,ax
         int  16h
         je   start
         pop  dx
         pop  cx
         pop  bx
         ret
```

Of course, if you do all that and you *still* can't get below the threshold, there's nothing *requiring* you to put the string in the boot code area. You could just as easily store them on another area which the boot code loads in as the first step. That way, you take away *all* the strings from the boot code area, saving some 460-odd bytes (adding maybe twenty back for the code to load the string sectors) and therefore coming in *well* under the threshold.

Comment: @fsdfff, you'll need to try harder :-)

Comment: @fsdfff, your wish is my command, see the update regarding your strings. That one string mentioned is *well* over the bytes you need to recover.

Comment: An observation is that Int 16h/AH=0h doesn't modify anything but AX. You can eliminate all the push and pops of the keyboard function.

Comment: Normally it's fine to write functions that clobber some registers anyway, as long as that's documented.  Most of this code doesn't keep any vars in regs across calls anyway, so push/pop is a total waste, especially for AX.  (Or if you insist on save/restore, pusha/popa is a win for code-size vs. multiple push/pop.)

Comment: @PeterCordes :only downside to pusha/popf is if he intends to load this on something pre-80186. Of course he's already using pusha/popf elsewhere so he probably doesn't care about being compatible with 8086/8088 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It's negative because `510 - code_size` is negative.  Your code is too big to fit in one sector as an MBR.

I commented out the padding line, and assembled your file.  The resulting binary is 652 bytes long (including the 2 bytes after the padding).  **`512 - 650 = -138`**.

Either code-golf your program so it does the same thing with fewer code bytes ([Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code)), or break it up into a boot sector that loads the rest of the code from disk after booting with BIOS calls.

With all those long strings, there's probably not a lot of room for saving 140 bytes here.  There's certainly room for significant saving, e.g. `mov ax, 07C0h` / `add ax, 288` is silly vs. `mov ax, 07C0h + 288` so there's 3 bytes you can save easily.

See [Enable the boot loader to load the second sector of a USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044706/enable-the-boot-loader-to-load-the-second-sector-of-a-usb) and  [How to load kernel or be able to use more space in own bootloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785448/how-to-load-kernel-or-be-able-to-use-more-space-in-own-bootloader)

Michael Petch's general bootloader development tips ([Boot loader doesn't jump to kernel code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701854/boot-loader-doesnt-jump-to-kernel-code/32705076#32705076)) should be helpful if you want to mess around with legacy BIOS stuff.

Your other option is to write a UEFI bootloader instead of legacy BIOS, so your code starts in 32 or 64-bit mode.  And more importantly, an EFI "application" can be any reasonable size, so the firmware can load all your code at once instead of you having to write code that loads the rest of itself.

---

Also, you incorrectly used `512 - size`, which won't leave room for the MBR signature 2 bytes at the end.  **Use `510 - ($ - $$)`**

See [Assembly Why when i modify the code the result gets unbootable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53796349) for more about that.

Comment: @fsdfff of course it's the same error if you don't change anything else.  Have you still not understood the rest of my answer, or Pax's?  Fixing that bug makes the size limit 2 bytes *smaller*.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I only answered this because of the different error message.  I don't remember seeing SO questions about a negative value from `times 510 - ($-$$)`.  Remember that people who aren't logged into SO (e.g. who got here from google on an error message like `TIMES value ... is negative`) will be redirected straight to the duplicate, without seeing this Q&A.  Despite this user wasting our time asking after already being pointed in the right direction, I think my answer here (with code-golf and links loading a 2nd sector) might be more useful for future readers with this error.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I think instead of closed-as-duplicate, a link to [Assembly Why when i modify the code the result gets unbootable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53796349) would be appropriate as a comment on the question, or a link inside one of the answers.