# Why cursor doesn't move vertically on real hardware but does on a virtual machine?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, osdev

I want to implement cursor movement using keys in my OS. I tried this code to do that:

```
mouse:
mov ah,0h
int 16h

    cmp al, 107
    je Down


    cmp al, 105
    je Up


    cmp al, 106
    je Left


    cmp al, 108
    je Right

    jmp mouse

    Right:
        add dl, 1
        call SetCursor
        jmp mouse
        ret

    Left:
      sub dl, 1
      call SetCursor
      jmp mouse
      ret

   Up:
     sub dh, 1
     call SetCursor
     jmp mouse
     ret

   Down:
      add dh, 1
      call SetCursor
      jmp mouse
      ret

   SetCursor:
       mov ah, 02h
       mov bh, 00
       int 10h
       ret
```

Bootloader (a little part of it):

```
%include "stage2info.inc"

STAGE2_LOAD_SEG  equ STAGE2_ABS_ADDR>>4

.stage2_loaded:
    mov ax, STAGE2_RUN_SEG      
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    jmp STAGE2_RUN_SEG:STAGE2_RUN_OFS

TIMES 510-($-$$) db  0
dw 0xaa55
```

Why cursor doesn't moves vertically on real hardware but does on a virtual machine?
I tried to change the keys but nothing, same.
Why the code doesn't work on real hardware?
Is my code wrong?

Comment: Where does this program run? Is this your whole code?  Does it run from within DOS?

Comment: It run bootable. Yes whole code is mine.

Comment: You `push` inside your loop without popping anything.  That will eventually overflow the stack, depending how close SP is to zero.  It's probably ok that you omit `org 0x7c00` because you don't have any static data, so your code is position-independent.  But you also left out the `0xaa55` boot signature at the end of your MBR, so maybe real hardware isn't booting it at all.

Comment: It's confusing that the `ret` instructions in your Up/.. blocks are never reached, because there's a `jmp` first.

Comment: @fsdfff That might be the issues.  Most BIOSes don't like to boot from a medium without a boot signature.

Comment: I puted the boot signature but no change...

Comment: @fsdfff Please post updated code with the boot signature in it.

Comment: it is in bootloader

Comment: yes it is based on it

Comment: it works only for up key , left key and right key. Down key on real hardware it still does not work.

Comment: What was it that made your code work?

Answer (score 4):

Issues and comments:

- To check for the arrow keys you need to look at the [scancodes](http://www.ee.bgu.ac.il/~microlab/MicroLab/Labs/ScanCodes.htm) in AH, not the ASCII characters in AL. Scan codes are 0x50 for down, 0x48 for up, 0x4b for left, and 0x4d for right
- You don't initialize *DH* and *DL* before entering your mouse loop. Retrieve the current coordinates with [Int 10h/AH=3h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0088.htm) before entering the loop
- You don't test the bounds going off the top, left, right, and bottom edges of the screen so if the cursor goes out of bounds unexpected things can happen
- You have unnecessary `ret` instructions after `jmp mouse` that can never be reached.
- You can use *INC* and *DEC* instructions to add or subtract one from a register rather than using *ADD* and *SUB* with a value of one.
- For people viewing the question, the bootloader being used is a template I put together in this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53860401/3857942).

This code should work:

```
%include "stage2info.inc"
ORG STAGE2_RUN_OFS

BITS 16

MAX_ROW equ 25                  ; 80x25 screen extents
MAX_COL equ 80

mouse:
    mov ah, 3                   ; Get cursor BIOS call
    mov bh, 0                   ; Page number is zero
    int 10h                     ; DH and DL will be set to current coordinates.

    mov ah,0h
    int 16h

    cmp ah, 0x50
    je Down

    cmp ah, 0x48
    je Up

    cmp ah, 0x4b
    je Left

    cmp ah, 0x4d
    je Right

    jmp mouse

    Right:
      inc dl
      cmp dl, MAX_COL           ; Test for right edge.
      jl right_bound_ok
      mov dl, MAX_COL-1
    right_bound_ok:
      call SetCursor
      jmp mouse

    Left:
      dec dl
      jge left_bound_ok         ; Test for left edge (<0?)

      mov dl, 0
    left_bound_ok:
      call SetCursor
      jmp mouse

    Up:
      dec dh
      jge up_bound_ok           ; Test for upper edge (<0?)

      mov dh, 0
    up_bound_ok:
      call SetCursor
      jmp mouse

    Down:
      inc dh
      cmp dh, MAX_ROW           ; Test for bottom edge
      jl down_bound_ok
      mov dh, MAX_ROW-1
    down_bound_ok:
      call SetCursor
      jmp mouse

    SetCursor:
      mov ah, 02h
      mov bh, 00
      int 10h
      ret
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186072/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-petch-why-cursor-doesnt-moves-verticaly-on-real).