# An error is printing two characters at once in BIOS

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, qemu, osdev

I am having an issue while programming in NASM. I am learning how to develop an OS purely in assembly and have started by creating a boot loader.

When I try to use the print function from the *print.asm* file, I encounter an error that prints two characters at a time.

File: bootloader.asm

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7c00]

mov al, 65
call print_char

%include "print.asm"

jmp $

times 512-($-$$) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

File: print.asm

```
print_char:
mov ah, 0x0e
mov bh, 0x00
mov bl, 0x07
int 0x10
ret
```

qemu: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ0wg.png)

Thank you all for the support!

Comment: `%include` the file so it does not land in the place that instruction pointer will just fall through. One letter is from the `call` the other one is just continuation of the execution of the instructions that `%include` puts where you use the directive.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike `include` in high level languages (where the compiler decides about where the external contents go), this `%include` will insert the contents of your *print.asm* file right where you have written the line. The true source code then becomes:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7c00]

mov al, 65
call print_char

print_char:
mov ah, 0x0e
mov bh, 0x00
mov bl, 0x07
int 0x10
ret

jmp $

times 512-($-$$) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

As you can see, once the `call print_char` returns, the code falls through in the *print_char* routine and thus executes the same instructions a second time (producing "AA").
Additionally, because the second time, the `ret` instruction has no sensible return address on the stack, the computer will crash, but in a dangerous way because there's no telling about where execution will go to!
If you want, the `jmp $` is also a crash but at least it's a 'safe' one.

This is what your code should have been:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]

mov al, 65
call print_char

cli
hlt
jmp $-2

%include "print.asm"

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

`times 512-($-$$) db 0` (**512** instead of **510**) was wrong because it forces the mandatory signature bytes out of the 512-bytes bootsector. I don't understand why your emulator even launches this code without a valid signature where it belongs!
`jmp $` is not wrong, but the preferred way is using `cli` `hlt` `jmp $-2`.

Comment: The HLL analogy of doing `include` in the wrong place would be in C putting `#include<stdio.h>` *inside* a function instead of global scope.  It *does* substitute right there in the source, but yeah the consequences would be different.  (Missing declarations elsewhere, or nested-function errors, instead of function definitions being inlined into this one.  That's one reason why it's weird to define global functions in an asm include file, although using a linker would be overkill for a boot sector.)

Comment: Also, we already have at least two canonical duplicates for %include in the path of execution in a bootloader or .com: [I'm making a bootloader but it fails with %include](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63704833) / [Assembly with %include at the top - Printing Outputs Unexpected Result: just an " S"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61072003).  Might want to move your answer to one of those if you want to explain in more detail than the existing answers.